# wordpress website after migrating doesnt works same

Tags: php, css, wordpress, seo

I just tried to migrate my worpress site to my local host wamp server i did backup database as well as all the files required but still i cant see the whole website i could just see a logo and all themes are gone as well as all the css is not shown however when i go to dashboard i could see all things. I even tried to move it to an online server hosting same issue occurs

Comment: Thanks for ignoring the warning when you posted this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the sites address in the database. Because the data is serialized you can't just update it with a simple query. I would recommend running [this serialized data tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/). I have no affiliation with the tool and it is free. I have used it a ton of times and it works great.

You will just replace the URL you used on your local machine with the one for the server you are running the tool on.

Answer (score -2):

Use PHPMyadmin or something to review the wp_options table. It likely still has references to your old server, like `'/home/user/directory/'` After making a backup copy of that table, find what the correct path is, and use the following MySQL query to correct your wp_options entries

```
update wp_options set `option_value` = replace(`option_value`, 
'OLD/WORDPRESS/DEV', 'NEW/WORDPRESS/SITE');
```

Comment: The wp_options table isn't the only one that needs to be updated. I would run the tool I recommended in my answer to be sure everything is updated properly.

Comment: I already updated all that i could see all the text of my website just not the css as well as plugins are lost